# Mocking objects instantiated inside a class to be tested

Tags: tdd, nunit, private

So I am learning TDD using the many resources here on SO, but I just cant seem to figure out what I do with private/protected objects instantiated inside a given method/constructor. Lets say I have a connection string. That connection string is used to construct a Sqlcommand or Sqlhelper. Well I want to mock that Sqlhelper so that when I test other methods I don't have to rely on the results coming from my database. But I cant access the Sqlhelper.

How do I work around this?

Answer (score 3):

Its generally best (except for a very few rare occasions) to test only the public interface of the class as a whole. Try not to use one of the workaround methods (such as private objects) unless you really have to. Accessing private members of classes in tests tends to look good at first as theres less code to write to test an object, however when things start to change (and they will) anything accessing the internals of a class makes it more difficult to change its implementation, this can be crippling to a project if most of the tests are written in this way.

In this particular case you are interacting with an external dependency outside of your control (i.e. SqlHelper), I'd recommend wrapping the SqlHelper object in your own object that implements an ISqlHelper interface (or a more reasonably named interface for your scenario).

e.g.

```
public interface ISqlHelperWrapper
{
    void ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Then inject this in through the constructor of you're object under test:

```
public class SqlConsumer
{
   private ISqlHelperWrapper _sqlHelper;

   public SqlConsumer(ISqlHelperWrapper helper)
   {
       this._sqlHelper = helper;
   }

   public void QuerySomething()
   {
       this._sqlHelper.ExecuteQuery();
   }
}
```

Not only is this a better design (you've isolated the sql implementation specific stuff from the SqlConsumer, and given it fewer reasons to change). But you can now mock the ISqlHelper instance using a mocking framework as well as switch the implementation on construction.

Given your connectionstring scenario above, you could initialise the sqlhelperwrapper (There are better names for this) with the connectionstring and your SqlConsumer object doesn't need to know about it.